# /textwidth error "missing number treated as zero"

Tags: subfloats

I am having trouble with the subfigure command, `\textwidth` comes up with the error `missing number treated as zero`

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackeage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.15/textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=/textwidth]{Fig3_FirstGeomG2}

    \label{fig:3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.15/textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=/textwidth]{Fig3_FirstGeomG5}


    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.15/textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=/textwidth]{Fig3_MeanDiff}

    \label{fig:4}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.15/textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=/textwidth]{Fig3_FirstGeom}

    \label{fig:5}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Is there a problem with my preamble? Many thanks

Comment: use `\ ` not `/ `

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As David says, you need `\textwidth`, not `/textwidth`, everywhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please, add an answer

Comment: @egreg always happy to give you a chance to vote for me.

Answer (score 3):

`/` is not a special character by default in TeX, you need to use `\` not `/` everywhere so

```
width=\textwidth
```

not

```
width=/textwidth
```